# Does the Couchbase REST API support NON-JSON data (binary data)

Tags: c, json, http, nosql, couchbase

I am storing c structures to couchbase, I am doing so so that I can read back these structures later and process directly, I am avoiding the steps of
1 )C structure - > JSON while storing
and
2 )JSON -> C structure while retrieving.

This is working well when I use lcb_get() and lcb_set() 
But I also need have a requirement for making hits to views using the REST model and lcb_make_http_request () call.

So I was wondering how the lcb_make_http_request () will handle my non-JSON C structure , which is hex data and may have nulls in between.
Will I still be able to extract and populate my C - structure with the data that I get as HTTP response after calling lcb_make_http_request () ?

Comment: It should work if you pass the data correctly as Couchbase can store JSON or binary data in a document. Although, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of docs for how. Base64 encoding certainly would work.

Answer (score 3):

As [WiredPrairie said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104465/does-the-couchbase-rest-api-support-non-json-data-binary-data#comment24751761_17104465) you aren't forced to use JSON and can store C structs, but keep in mind [byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and [field alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) when you are doing so.

When server detects that your data isn't in JSON format it will encode it using base64 and set `meta.type` to `"json"` when the document comes to map function.

And you will be able to emit your complete document as a value if you'd like to get the value in the HTTP stream. In case of this simple map function:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (meta.type == "base64") {
    emit(meta.id);
  }
}
```

You will get response like this one (I've formatted it for clarity):

```
{
    "total_rows": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "foo",
            "key": "foo",
            "value": "4KwuAgAAAAA="
        }
    ]
}
```

It does mean that you must use some json parser to extract `"value"` attribute from result, decode it and you will get exactly the same bytestream, you have sent it with SET command.

Comment: Also I've written a small blogpost with example map function to analyze binary data: http://avsej.net/2013/analyzing-binary-data-in-couchbase/